# Can I identify a form button by name via javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, button

One of my forms has several buttons like so:

```
<input type="submit" name="some_name" value="some_value">
```

I would like to, in the on_load function for the page, add some functionality to some of these buttons.

How do I locate this button in the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function getElementsByName takes in a name and gives all the elements with that name. If you're pretty sure that only one element has that name or the element your trying to access is the first element in your code with that name,then:

```
document.getElementsByName('some_name')[0];
```

will give you access to your button.

```
var button = document.getElementsByName('some_name')[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var myButton = document.getElementsByName('some_name')[0];
```